# How to get the data in python-twitter

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I'm new to python.
I am using the libray called `python-twitter` to grab data of my own twitter account

Here is my code (twitter-test.py)

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key="xxxxxxxx",
                  consumer_secret="xxxxxxxxxx",
                  access_token_key="xxxxxx-xxxx",
                  access_token_secret="xxxxxxx",
                  sleep_on_rate_limit=True)
follower = api.GetFollowers()
print(follower)
```

then i run `python3 twitter-test.py`
Here is the result.

```
[User(ID=xxxxxxxxx, ScreenName=xxxxxxx), User(ID=xxxxxxxxx, ScreenName=xxxxxxx), User(ID=xxxxxxxxx, ScreenName=xxxxxxx), .......]
```

The api is call successfully.

Now I want to save the result:

```
import json

{ The code same as before }

json.dumps(follower)
```

```
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
```

Then I tried to loop the result using `for x in follower:`

but `x[0]` `x['ID']` `x.ID` all return error:

```
TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I extract the data from `User` Object ?

Comment: it returns you list of tuples so just try for x in follower: x[0] # x[1]

Comment: @Sibyl TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is works fine for me

GetFollowers() function returns an user object in a list [you can find object details here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object)

```
followers = api.GetFollowers()
for follower in followers:
    print(follower.created_at)
    print(follower.name)
```